# "Failed to load native TensorFlow runtime."

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

So I created a program to load a dataset from TensorFlow and I got an error that I have no idea what it means.

My code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

data = keras.dataset_fashion_mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = data.data_load()

print(train_labels[1])
```

I supposed to get a number as output and not an error.

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Khosr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I have no idea what to do to solve this and what to try. I made sure that I have tensorflow installed and I do.
I think it has something to do with the library itseff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error seems similar to this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794

The general solution there is to use a specific version of CUDA with a specific version of tensorflow, e.g.

```
tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
python 3.6.8
CUDA v10.0
cudnn 7.4.1.5
```

Can you provide your library version? I'd recommend using `conda` to install tensorflow on Windows as it helps a lot with installing the right versions instead of setting things up yourself.

**Edit**

Please try these steps (Taken from Tensorflow's document: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

1. Go to the Visual Studio downloads: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/
2. Select Redistributables and Build Tools
3. Download and install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable
   Update 3

Enable long paths on windows: https://superuser.com/questions/1119883/windows-10-enable-ntfs-long-paths-policy-option-missing

Finally, please make sure your CPU supports AVX instructions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#CPUs_with_AVX

Comment: I am using tensorflow 2.0.0

Comment: Also, I can't install CUDA because I get this error:
```
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement CUDA==10.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for CUDA==10.0
```

Comment: Does your GPU support CUDA? How did you install CUDA? Did you follow this guide: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/ or something else?

Comment: I have an intel GPU so I don't think it supports it.

Comment: If that's the case, just to be sure, you are using `tensorflow`, not `tensorflow-gpu` right? I don't think `tensorflow-gpu`  would work witth an Intel GPU.

I have updated the answer with additional steps to install MSVC and enable long paths on Windows, can you try them out?
If that still does not work can you provide your CPU model?

Comment: My CPU is a Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 4405U @ 2.10GHz 2.10GHz.
The answer above did not work because my CPU did not support it. Someone on Code Project recommended me to install Anaconda and so I am doing that right now. I will if that works and update you on it.

Comment: If so, you'd need to install an older version of tensorflow (From their site: `Starting with TensorFlow 1.6, binaries use AVX instructions which may not run on older CPUs.`). And yes, `conda` will make your life easier.

Comment: What is their website? I downloaded Tensorflow 1.14 and I still get the error even with Conda. Could you please tell me step by step how to do so?

Comment: You can check the installation guide here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip 
 
Versions >= 1.6 needs AVX instructions, which your CPU does not, version 1.14 is >= 1.6 so it won't work on your computer. 

Personally I don't think you can do much with your CPU. Did you look into options like Google Colabs (https://colab.research.google.com/) which you can try things out (which seems like what you want to do) for free on much better hardwares without having to do any installations/setup

Comment: So I can run and train my AI without any issues?

Comment: If you mean Google Colabs then there are many things already setup for you like tensorflow, keras, torch, numpy, ... It depends on what you need because I don't know what your "AI" is. And if you want to know more about Google Colabs please create another question, someone else maybe able to provide better help.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I am 13 so I don't entirely understand so if I asked too many questions and acted stupid then I am sorry. I am doing this for my Science Fair Project and I still don't know what I will make it do. I am currently using the Fashion dataset provided by Tensorflow to create my "AI" so it will just be indentifying that for now. I will post another question about that matter soon.

Comment: Oh I see, if it's only for that purpose I think Google Colab should be good enough for your needs. Just check their website out for some basic example, you can treat the algorithms/maths involved as black boxes that "just works" at first to understand how the components interact with each other for your purpose I guess. But if you really want to be serious about this, please look for materials to learn and understand them.

Comment: I am looking through courses to help me out and really the purpose is to find the best properties for a neural network. Changing the data, learning rate, type, and others. The dataset I used worked perfectly so I believe that the best way to tackle this issue for me is to use Google Colab. If for any reason there is a issue with it I will update this post if related or post a new question. For now I think I will leave it.