# "ImportError: DLL load failed" building Chatbot

Tags: python, python-3.6, chatbot, tensor

I am a Python newb and I am getting this error while building a Chatbot. It is a Tensorflow Package error and I am not sure why I am getting it. I am building the Chatbot with Python 3.6. This is the error I have been getting...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aryan/PycharmProjects/chatbot/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 69, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\aryan\PycharmProjects\chatbot\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\aryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Here is my current code for the Chatbot as requested:

```py
#import Statements
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
import numpy
import tflearn
import tensorflow
import random
import json

#Access Intents JSON file
with open('intents.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

#Array Studier
words = []
labels = []
docs_x = []
docs_y = []

#Chatbot Interpreter and Responder
for intent in data['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.extend(wrds)
        docs_x.append(wrds)
        docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent['tag'] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent['tag'])
```

Any help is much appreciated :)!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us your code?

Comment: Hi @DanielWalker,
Thank you for the quick response. Sorry for my late response. I edited my post with code and your help is greatly appreciated! I look forward to receiving help from you!

Comment: This seems a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58829887/failed-to-load-native-tensorflow-runtime