# Trying to import tensorflow on jupyter notebook, keep getting ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. error

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda3

Please help as I think I have tried everything. I tried reinstalling anaconda and installing tensorflow through anaconda, but it was an older version. Once I tried updating to 2.2 I am now getting this error. See stack trace below. I have also tried fixing the environmental variable with no luck as well.

Processor: Intel I7
OS: Windows 64 bit

---

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
`

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

[Environmental Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq3nH.png)

[File Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q7Bc.png)

Comment: ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\owner\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [“Failed to load native TensorFlow runtime”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58831949/8890345) The linked question has instructions on how to install the Visual C++ 2015 redistributable and how to enable long paths on Windows.

Comment: It appears I can't install gpedit.msc. I am also trying to use anaconda and jupyter notebook as per the tutorial I am following. Is there another way?

Comment: You can enable long paths via the registry https://superuser.com/a/1119948/859490

Comment: I used the "Using the Registry instead at HKLM Level" method and reinstalled anaconda. used pip install tensorflow, tried to import it again on jupyter notebook and got "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Also tried using spyder, received the same error

Comment: Did you install the redistributable?

Comment: From googling it looks like that is for visual studio, is there another such thing for anaconda?

Comment: I installed gpedit.msc using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UA885sqU2lg . And i followed how to enable the long paths using the link you sent and local group policy editor. But still getting the following error.  ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: Please see what i have edited so far here. https://imgur.com/a/TOFPTQ1

Comment: You can use [Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51606222/8890345) tool to find out what DLL you are missing.

Comment: How can I be missing something when I've uninstalled/reinstalled 100 times?

Comment: Please try using dependencies tool in the linked answer (download from Releases page of the github repo linked in the answer) to see if your _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.pyd library is missing a DLL. "The specified module could not be found" might mean a missing DLL library. Also do you have CUDA 10 installed and cuDNN?

Comment: Finally got it to work by downloading visual studio python ide. THanks for all ytour help nathan